# Android interstitial request

Tags: android, admob, onpause, interstitial

I'm trying to show Admob Interstitial in my android app when loading the next activity. But at the point at which my first activity is being paused to load the next activity the interstitial ad did not have time to load (due to slow internet speed for example).

Can someone please help me with a method to continue the ad request between activities so that it will then be displayed on screen?

For now `displayInterstitial()` is in the `onResume()` method of the first activity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public InterstitialAd interstitial;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        scrool = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrool);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        requestInterstitial();
    }

    public void requestInterstitial() {
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
            if (buttons.get(i).getId() == v.getId()) {
                Intent trimite = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecipeView.class);
                Bundle colet = new Bundle();
                colet.putString("key", Content.RETETE[i]);
                colet.putInt("keyimg", drawableId.get(i));
                trimite.putExtras(colet);
                startActivity(trimite);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        displayInterstitial();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set an AdListener you can tell your interstitial to be shown when it is done loading even if onDestroy has been called on the activity that loaded it.

```
 public void requestInterstitial() {
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("****************");
    AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);

     interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(){
            super.onAdLoaded();

                interstitial.show();

        }
    });
}
```

Careful with this because depending on what your next activity contains your interstitial may interrupt the flow and degrade the user experience.